# Translation of "Mors dolorum omnium exsolutio est et finis"

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation, sentence-translation, seneca-iunior

What is the proper translation of the phrase (though, I am not sure it is a complete phrase):

> Mors dolorum omnium exsolutio est et finis

As far as I can see, this is an excerpt from [section 19 from Of Consolation: To Marcia by Seneca the Younger](http://www.latin.it/autore/seneca/de_consolatione_ad_marciam/19.lat).

By comparing it side-by-side to the [translation by Aubrey Stewart](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Of_Consolation:_To_Marcia#XIX.), I can see that the whole sentence, which is:

> Mors dolorum omnium exsolutio est et finis ultra quem mala nostra non exeunt, quae nos in illam tranquillitatem in qua antequam nasceremur iacuimus reponit.

was translated as:

> Death is a release from and an end of all pains: beyond it our sufferings cannot extend: it restores us to the peaceful rest in which we lay before we were born.

So I am concluding, that mentioned excerpet must be translated as:

> Death is a release from and an end of all pains

Am I correct in this assumption? (and if not - what is the proper translation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumption is correct!

Moving the words around to correspond to the English word order:

> Mors est

Death is…

> exsolutio et finis

…a release and an end…

> dolorum omnium

…of all pains.

You could also use "suffering" or "sorrow(s)" for *dolōrum* here, if you prefer, and/or "every" for *omnium*. But the idea is the same.